# Spark EC2 - Broken Pipe error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

**Getting following error while spinning Spark (1.6) cluster on EC2 with spark-ec2 script. I tried with --resume option but the error is consistant.**

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to
<<host>>: Broken pipe Traceback (most recent call last): File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1535, in
  <module>

    main() File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1527, 
    in main real_main() File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1363, 
    in real_main setup_cluster(conn, master_nodes, slave_nodes, opts, True) File "./spark_ec2.py", line 811, 
    in setup_cluster dot_ssh_tar = ssh_read(master, opts,
    ['tar', 'c', '.ssh']) File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1209, 
    in ssh_read ssh_command(opts) + ['%s@%s' % (opts.user, host), stringify_command(command)]) File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1203, 
    in _check_output raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd,
    output=output)
```

Comment: I suppose that you have credentials and access for aws service to run ec2 clusters

Comment: Yes I am using valid identity file while spinning off. Also I can see the EC2 instances in running state through AWS console. The error comes only when spark-ec2 script tries to set up the cluster by SSHing into the master.